# Dar formato de string con fecha a DateTime

Tags: c#

Tengo un string con la fecha tal que así:
string fecha = 20210708
string hora= 51012
Y me gustaría parsearlo para poder darle formato tal que así:
2021/07/08 5:10:12 o cualquiera similar

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma mas sencilla de convertir cadenas a fechas es usar `DateTime.TryParseExact`. A este método puedes pasarle una cadena definiendo el formato de los datos de entrada e intentara convertirlo a `DateTime`, devolviendo `false` si no ha sido capaz.

Te pongo un pequeño ejemplo de como sería:

```
string fecha= "20210708";
string hora = "51012";
DateTime fechaHora;
    
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    
if (hora.Length==5)
{
    hora="0" + hora;
}
    
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fecha + " " + hora, "yyyyMMdd hhmmss", provider,
                             DateTimeStyles.None, out fechaHora))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fechaHora.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("error al convertir");
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que la hora puede darte problemas. Aqui hago una pequeña comprobación para añadir un 0 al inicio si solo tiene 5 caracteres, asumiendo que el problema es que falta un digito de la hora. Pero si fueran los minutos los que tuvieran solo un digito, la conversión fallaría.

Answer (score 0):

Si trabajas con string, y no necesitas formato de fecha específica, podrías utilizar

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //para el string sin formato con año, mes y día
        string fecha = "20211201";
        //creamos un nuevo string "an" y con el método Substring de la clase string, desde el caracter 0, o sea, desde el principio del string, tomamos los primeros 4 caracteres y lo metemos en la variable "an"
        string an = fecha.Substring(0,4);
        //creamos un nuevo string "me", desde el caracter 4 (Los que han correspondido al año) del string, tomamos 2 caracteres y lo metemos en la variable "me", sería el mes
        string me = fecha.Substring(4, 2);
        //aquí partiríamos del carácter 6 (4 para el año + 2 para el mes), serían los últimos 2 caracteres que meteríamos en la variable "di" de días
        string di = fecha.Substring(6, 2);
```

Para las horas variamos un poco el proceso:

Para el string sin formato de la hora, que estimo pueda ser con formato 24 horas y pueda tener horas de un dígito en madrugada y dos por el día hacemos un condicional que evalúe si el string tiene 5 ó 6 caracteres

```
        //tenemos el string de la hora
        string hora = "51222";
        //creamos tres nuevos string para "ho", "mi" y "se" vacíos
        string ho = "";
        string mi = "";
        string se = "";

        //si el string hora tiene 5 caracteres
        if (hora.Length == 5)
        {
            //para "ho" tomamos el primero desde cero, para "mi" dos caracteres desde 1, y los últimos 2 para "se" desde 3
            ho = hora.Substring(0, 1);
            mi = hora.Substring(1, 2);
            se = hora.Substring(3, 2);
        }
        else if (hora.Length == 6)
        {
            //si el string tiene 6 caracteres, tomamos 2, 2 y dos
            ho = hora.Substring(0, 2);
            mi = hora.Substring(2, 2);
            se = hora.Substring(4, 2);
        }
        //ahora lo imprimimos en pantalla con el formato de fecha y hora, aunque también podemos formar nuevas variables con ese mismo formato
        Console.WriteLine(di + "/" + me + "/" + an);
        String fechaFormateada = di + "/" + me + "/" + an;
        Console.WriteLine(ho + ":" + mi + ":" + se);
        String horaFormateada = ho + ":" + mi + ":" + se;
    }
```

Si deseas que en la hora, siempre te aparezcan 6 dígitos, con el "0" delante de las horas cuando solo haya un dígito, podrías usar:

```
//en el if de los 5 dígitos
se = "0" + hora.Substring(3, 2);
```

Las salidas por consola del formateo de fecha y hora, serían:

[image: Salidas por consola]